# Trying to extract data using python/scrapy and not able to find the correct xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I wanted to scrape the website.

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab

I want to extract

- Title
- Location
- Company

of the job postings.

I tried few xpath's for the location,company and title and nothing was working. I also tried to write it to a CSV file. All location,company and title comes out blank. I think my xpath is not correct

```
import scrapy


class JobItem(scrapy.Item):
    # Data structure to store the title, company name and location of the job
    title = scrapy.Field()
    company = scrapy.Field()
    location = scrapy.Field()

class stackoverflow(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stack_bot'
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab']

    def parse(self, response):
        for a_el in response.xpath('//div[@class="listResults"]'):
            section = JobItem()
            section['title']   = ?
            section['company'] = ?
            section['location'] = ?
            yield section
```

Can anyone help me with the xpath for the title,company and location. Also the `xpath('//div[@class="listResults"]')` is correct.

Comment: To add to the answer. Look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348954/can-i-scrape-stack-overflow-job-postings) for the discussion about scraping SO jobs in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that `xpath('//div[@class="listResults"]')` is correct. It gives only one element. Here is my version of code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for a_el in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "-job-summary")]'):
        section = JobItem()
        section['title']   = a_el.css('h2 a::text').get()
        section['company'] = a_el.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "-company")]/span[1]/text()').get()
        section['location'] = a_el.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "-company")]/span[2]/text()').get()
        yield section
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the RSS feed as source as this will be more robust over time

```
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed
```

Then you can use the following css selectors to generate lists you can list(zip()) together

titles selector: `item title`

companies selector: `a10\:author`

locations: `location`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and much appreciated. I tried the first one and it worked. Thanks again :-)